# function of modular in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am new to the PL/SQL, and I am trying to implement modular function.

I believe this job is quite easy, and the language for SQL just like python somehow, however, I am getting trouble about using cursor (it seems like necessary in my program), but instead of using cursor, is there any ways can done this program only using if/else & loop? (although it asks cursor, but I do believe it not necessary...)

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

accept p_num1 prompt 'Please enter the number: '

declare
    myint  number(10):= &p_num1;

begin
    if myint is null THEN        
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(0);
    else
        for i in myint loop
            if mod(i,2) = 0 then
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This is even' || i);
            else
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This is odd' || i);
            end if;
        end loop;
    end if;

exception
    when others then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You get whatever errors');
end;
/
```

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 8, column 18:
PLS-00456: item 'MYINT' is not a cursor
ORA-06550: line 8, column 9:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: I think you meant [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) not modular.

Answer (score 5):

Should be

```
for i in 1 .. myint loop
```